# How to parse a web page containing CSS and HTML using python

Tags: python, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

Am trying to parse and extract some information from a web page that contains CSS and of course HTML. I am using cssutils and beatifulsoup for this. Lets say I want to find out the font size used for a table heading. Beautifulsoup tells me where the table definition is in HTML. But if I want to know which style is used in the table do I get that information from BeatifulSoup? If not how do I go about solving this problem. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you give example code?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you get it. [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html) is perfect the choice and with regular expression is  strong power :)

Example:

> ```
> import re
> from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
>
>
> soup = BeautifulSoup('<h1 style="font-size: 12px; margin: 5px">Test</h>')
> style = soup.find('h1')['style']
> re.findall('font-size[^;]+', style)
> # [u'font-size: 12px']
> ```